# using morphic step method outside the UI

Tags: pharo

I'd like to have a class respond to the morphic "step" message - but the class doesn't need to be displayed (directly)... so it's not a Morph

is there a way to use this message outside of morphic, or is there a morph without a displayed UI?

with thanks

Chris

Answer (score 3):

World doOneCycle may help.

The UI process repeatedly calls World doOneCycle. You can do that too. Just ensure your do that in the main thread.